# Submerge/Reveal Tab Bar

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

How can I submerge and reveal tab bar in iOS like the [Groupon iPhone app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/groupon/id352683833?mt=8) does?

Answer (score 1):

Use a pseudo tab bar if you don't want to mess with the actual tab bar framework, subclassing etc. For example, put a segmented controller onto a view that is no bigger than the controller, size the view and controller to the size of a tab bar and just animate the origin of this custom view. Would be pretty easy and you could get it on and off the screen whenever desired with similar functionality to a tab bar.

Just one option...